# EntityQuery with fieldcondition of link field

Tags: 7

I have a field called `field_url` which is of type `link`. I want to query and fetch all those nodes which have `field_url` value like eg. `www.google.com`. I tried using the below code:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'websites')
  ->fieldCondition('field_url','value','%google%','like');
  $result = $query->execute();
```

I get database error with this. I saw the values stored in `field_data_field_url` table and they look like serialized. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: There's no way to filter by serialised PHP properties through a DB query. If the data you need is in a serialised string, you'll either need to come up with a `LIKE/REGEXP` expression that reliably matches what you're looking for, or load all row in PHP and extract the relevant rows after deserialising the data